# HTTPS not secured brons

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I'm currently using https on my WordPress site, but it keeps having a yellow square in front of the https:// because not everything on the page is secured.

I'm sure there is a way to solve this problem in htaccess but I don't know.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

(I'm already forcing https via wordpress settings)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to use mod_rewrite to fix this.

If you could redirect the insecure resource (which would depend on it being on the same host) to HTTPS, then there would still be an initial insecure request made over HTTP to get the redirect instruction.

You need to find out what resources are being requested insecurely and change whatever is referencing them.